# Custom Powershell Provider occasionally has a null PSDriveInfo

Tags: powershell

I've created a custom `NavigationCmdletProvider` and implemented all of the required methods.  I have a custom `PSDriveInfo` object that manages the connection to the backend service I'm using, but I've noticed that Powershell seems to continually call methods on my provider class with a null `PSDriveInfo`.  Since I need the `PSDriveInfo` to do the lookup of the object, my only option in this case is to return false.

I've added a bunch of logging and I get lines like:

```
Found item at path Foo\Bar\Baz.  Has DriveInfo? True
Item at path Foo\Bar\Baz doesn't exist.  Has DriveInfo? False
Exception thrown: 'System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException' in System.Management.Automation.dll
```

Is there a reason that this is happening?  Is there any way to stop this from happening?  It causes a very large number of ItemNotFoundExceptions to be thrown, usually at least on per item in a container, so it slows things down and makes it difficult to find sources of errors.

Comment: In which methods does this occur?

Comment: The one that I'm seeing it in is ItemExists().  It's obviously in my class, so it's aware that the path it's looking at is from one of my drives, but it doesn't seem to know which.